# SSRS 2008R2 multi valued parameter in shared datasets

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, reporting, shared

i create a multidimensional report with a couple of multi value parameters. In the next step, i convert the datasets in shared datasets. Actually my problem is that i cant add parameters to the shared dataset in the report.

Can anybody explain, how i add multi or single Parameters to a shared dataset in a report?

Parameter1 - Dataset:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Unique] AS [Dimension1].[Dimension1].CurrentMember.UniqueName MEMBER [Measures].[Caption] AS [Dimension1].[Dimension1].CurrentMember.Member_Caption MEMBER [Measures].[Level] AS [Dimension1].[Dimension1].CurrentMember.Level.ordinal SELECT { [Measures].[Unique],[Measures].[Caption],[Measures].[Level]} ON COLUMNS,  NONEMPTY([Dimension1].[Dimension1].[Dimension1]) ON ROWS FROM [Cube]
```

Parameter2 - Dataset:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Unique] AS [Dimension2].[Dimension2].CurrentMember.UniqueName MEMBER [Measures].[Caption] AS [Dimension2].[Dimension2].CurrentMember.Member_Caption MEMBER [Measures].[Level] AS [Dimension2].[Dimension2].CurrentMember.Level.ordinal SELECT { [Measures].[Unique],[Measures].[Caption],[Measures].[Level]} ON COLUMNS,  NONEMPTY([Dimension2].[Dimension2].[Dimension2]) ON ROWS FROM [Cube]
```

Both Datasets are shared Datasets. In the report the first Dataset should filter the second Dataset.

How can i set a Parameter for the second Dataset?

Comment: Consider pasting your codes for this as well. Otherwise it is not clear to identify your approach and help....

Comment: Did you checkout these examples .. [Passing Date Parameter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337401(v=sql.105).aspx), [Passing Multi Value Parameter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337396(v=sql.105).aspx)